# How to display empty datatable on page load with input type text

Tags: java, jquery, html, datatables

I want to develop a functionality in which when user loads a page I have to display empty datatable with `<input type="text" />` in all the related columns. Now user can add in his data in all the columns and rows and will click on Submit. Once it is submitted, I want to take whole data and pass it to server side.

Is this feasible to develop? If so, any links how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/16737/individual-column-filtering-meets-ajax-source) can help you for the general idea.

And [this doc](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for implementation